# CSS not recognising class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

Trying to adjust the height & width of an image, but the CSS isn't recognising the class/isn't working.
I know my class method is different to my other classes, but when I try and make it the same, it gives a error message.
I'm using the Ruby language. It's probably going to be something simple, but I'm too new at this to understand.
Also having a problem with Twitter bootstrap rows. I'll be forever grateful if you can see anything wrong with that too.

HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'lego-man' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1><%= @user.profile.first_name %> <%= @user.profile.last_name %></h1>
      <h3><%= @user.profile.job_title %></h3>
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Decription</h3>
        <%= @user.profile.description %>
      </div>
      <% if current_user.plan_id == 2 %>
        <div class="well">
          <h3>Contact Information</h3>
          <%= @user.profile.phone_number %><br/>
          <%= @user.profile.contact_email %><br/>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.lego-man {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

Comment: where are you writing this `css` code. I mean in which file?

Comment: It's within the stylesheet folder. Do you want the name or?

Comment: try to put `display: none` inside `.lego-man {`, and let's see if these css working or not

Comment: Sorry, this is my 2nd stylesheet. I've got 2 stylesheets in my folder. Would that change anything? Surely you're allowed multiple sheets

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this

```
 <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url , size: "128x128" %>
```

For reference

Click here:- https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: hard coding it like that worked(thank you!), but just wondering why the classes didn't work? Just trying to learn, so I can avoid it in the future

Comment: For your previous code ,try like this once
By adding parathesis                                      .     

<%= image_tag (@user.profile.avatar.url), class: 'lego-man' %>

Comment: No, that just gave an error message. Not expecting ','. I removed that, but then it said unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')' , but my code is already closed off. <%= image_tag(@user.profile.avatar.url) class: 'lego-man' %>

Comment: I hope I am not wasting your time.
but  if  you  have  time can you try this

<%= image_tag(@user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'lego-man') %>

Comment: Not at all! I appreciate the help! This error is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the `CSS` code you are writing is properly loading.

> e.g. in your `layouts/application.html.erb` contains this type of line
>   to load `application.css`
>
> ```
> <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
> ```
>
> And that `css` containing file is included in `application.css`

Answer (score 0):

In rails, three methods are available to add your css styles.

1. Add this style property Inline in image_tag

   ```
   <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url, :style => "width: 128px; height: 128px;" %>
   ```
2. Add this style property internally in same file using `<style>` tags

   ```
   <style>
     .lego-man {
       width: 128px;
       height: 128px;
     }
   </style>
   ```
3. Add this css property externally in **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

Answer (score 0):

```
.lego-man {
  width: 128px!important;
  height: 128px!important;
}
```

try using over ride your class.

```
<div class: 'lego-man'>
  <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url %>
</div>
```

and then add
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>` to application layout